# Timeout Expired (cmd.CommandTimeout = 0 being ignored)

Tags: sql, vb.net, timeout, sapb1

I'm receiving this error:

> Timeout Expired

even after setting the `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0`.

The query is pulling from a SAP database, in SAP the SQL query runs fine however when I try run it on an adapter in visual studio I get that Timeout Expired error.

Is there something I am missing?
How do I extend the timeout period so my query can run?

Here's my VB.Net code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim ds As New DataSet
  Dim dv As New DataView
  Dim ConStr As String = "Data Source= .\SQLOLEDB.1;Password=Password;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=User;Initial Catalog=XXX;Data Source=xxx.xxx.x.x;Connection Timeout=0"
  Dim cn As SqlConnection
  Try
      cn = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
      cn.Open()
      Dim cmd = cn.CreateCommand()
      cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
      Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("/* SELECT FROM [dbo].[OITM] T2 */" &
                                        " DECLARE @Whs_From AS VARCHAR(10)" &
                                        " DECLARE @Whs_To AS VARCHAR(10)" &
                                        "/* WHERE */" &
                                        " SET @Whs_From = /* T2.DfltWH */ 'AUT-L-N'" &
                                        " SET @Whs_To = /* T2.DfltWH */ 'AUT-L-N'" &
                                        " SELECT    QUT1.[ItemCode] AS 'Code'," &
                                        " ISNULL(SUM(QUT1.[OpenQty]), 0) AS 'Open'" &
                                        " INTO  #QuoteSum" &
                                        " FROM  QUT1 QUT1 INNER JOIN OITM OITM ON QUT1.[ItemCode] = OITM.[ItemCode] INNER JOIN OQUT OQUT ON QUT1.[DocEntry] = OQUT.[DocEntry]" &
                                        " WHERE     QUT1.[WhsCode] = OITM.[DfltWH] AND QUT1.[LineStatus] = 'O' AND OQUT.[Canceled] != 'Y' GROUP BY QUT1.[ItemCode]" &
                                        " SELECT    QUT1.[ItemCode] AS 'Code'," &
                                        " SUM(QUT1.[quantity]) AS 'Last360'" &
                                        " INTO  #Last360" &
                                        " FROM  QUT1 QUT1 INNER JOIN OITM OITM ON QUT1.[ItemCode] = OITM.[ItemCode] INNER JOIN OQUT OQUT ON QUT1.[DocEntry] = OQUT.[DocEntry]" &
                                        " WHERE     QUT1.[WhsCode] = OITM.[DfltWH] AND CONVERT(CHAR, QUT1.[DocDate], 112) < CONVERT(CHAR, GetDate()-270, 112) AND CONVERT(CHAR, QUT1.[DocDate], 112) >= CONVERT(CHAR, GetDate()-360, 112) AND OQUT.[Canceled] != 'Y'" &
                                        " GROUP BY QUT1.[ItemCode]" &
                                        " SELECT    OITW.[WhsCode] AS 'Warehouse'," &
                                        " OITW.[ItemCode] AS 'Item Code'," &
                                        " OITM.[ItemName] AS 'Item Description'," &
                                        " ISNULL(QuoteSum.[Open], 0) AS 'Sales Quote Qty'," &
                                        " OITW.[IsCommited] AS 'Sales Order Qty'," &
                                        " (ISNULL(QuoteSum.[Open], 0) + OITW.[IsCommited]) AS 'Demand'," &
                                        " OITW.[OnHand] AS 'In Stock Qty', OITW.[OnOrder] AS 'Purchase Order Qty'," &
                                        " (OITW.[OnHand] + OITW.[OnOrder]) AS 'Available'," &
                                        " OITW.[OnHand] - OITW.[IsCommited] - ISNULL(QuoteSum.[Open], 0) + OITW.[OnOrder] AS 'To Manufacture/Buy'," &
                                        " Last360.[Last360] as 'Last 271-360'" &
                                        " FROM  OITW OITW LEFT OUTER JOIN #QuoteSum QuoteSum ON OITW.[ItemCode] = QuoteSum.[Code] INNER JOIN OITM OITM ON OITW.[ItemCode] = OITM.[ItemCode] AND OITW.[WhsCode] = OITM.[DfltWH] LEFT OUTER JOIN #Last360 Last360 ON OITW.[ItemCode] = Last360.[Code]" &
                                        " WHERE     OITM.[DfltWH] >=@Whs_From AND OITM.[DfltWH] <= @Whs_To" &
                                        " BEGIN DROP TABLE #QuoteSum END" &
                                        " BEGIN DROP TABLE #Last360 END;", cn)
      ad.Fill(ds, "OITM")
      dv.Table = ds.Tables("OITM")
      Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
  Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ErrorToString)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the exact error message I am getting:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout
> period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
> not responding.    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
> runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, DbAsyncResult result)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
> dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
> String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
> startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
> CommandBehavior behavior)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
> srcTable)    at CR_Test.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> in c:\users\leroif\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CR Test\CR
> Test\Form1.vb:line 46

Comment: Can you post the ***exact*** error message along with the error stack trace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding the timeout value on the wrong object.

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
```

But you don't actually use the `cmd` object anywhere after that.  It doesn't look like you even need to create a command object at all.  Your query is performed using the `ad` `SqlDataAdapter` instance, not the `cmd` instance.

What you need to do is override the timeout value for the `SqlDataAdapter`.

I've never tried it myself, but apparently, this is how it's done:

```
ad.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=0
```

Give that a try.

Comment: Also: there are separate timeouts on command and connection objects.

Comment: @Joel: But the timeout on the connection serves a different purpose. Am I misunderstanding what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Place the below code before Try statement then it will not ignore

```
 Dim cmd = cn.CreateCommand()
 cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
```